# Fast way to create $[ I_4\otimes e_1,\ \dots ,\ I_4 \otimes e_T]$?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, tensors

Is there a fast way to construct this matrix?

$\left[\begin{array}{c}
I_4\otimes e_1\\
\vdots \\
I_4 \otimes e_T \end{array}\right]$

$e_i$ is the $i$-th column of the matrix $I_T$, $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product.

$I_4\otimes e_t= \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
 e_t & 0\cdot e_t & 0 \cdot e_t & 0 \cdot e_t\\
0 \cdot e_t & e_t & 0 \cdot e_t & 0 \cdot e_t\\
0 \cdot e_t & 0 \cdot e_t & e_t & 0 \cdot e_t\\
0 \cdot e_t & 0 \cdot e_t & 0 \cdot e_t & e_t
\end{array}\right]_{4T\times 4}$

$e_t$ has dimensions $T\times 1$.

$T$ will be in the order of at least 200.

I'm looking for a "vectorized way" of building this matrix. I don't want to have to define it elementwisely, since this will take a lot of time for big values of $ T $.

Comment: Have you tried KroneckerProduct?

Comment: @bills I've edited my question. I know the existence of that function. My problem is that I want to create the matrix as a whole, without having to define it componentwise...

Comment: So what `Dimensions` do the inputs get and what `Dimensions` should the output have?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ I've added the dimensions. The only thing that may change is the value of $T$ depending on the iteration.

Comment: Is $ I_T $ the $ T $ dimensional identity matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**
You may use the [`ArrayRules`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayRules.html) syntax of [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html).

```
ClearAll[specialFromRules]
specialFromRules[t_, i_] :=
 SparseArray[
  Flatten@
   MapIndexed[
    {(#1 - 1) (t i) + #2 t - (t - #1), #2} & @@ #2 -> #1 &,
    ConstantArray[1, {t, i}],
    {2}
    ],
  {t t i , i}
  ]
```

then

```
specialFromRules[2, 2] // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

and

```
specialFromRules[2, 4] // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

---

---

Previous method from [`IdentityMatrix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IdentityMatrix.html) is not as fast as above `SparseArray` `ArrayRules` method.

You may use [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) with [`Band`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Band.html).

With a helper function to build the blocks,

```
ClearAll[specialMatrix]
specialMatrix[t_, i_] :=
 Function[{et},
   SparseArray[
    Map[
     Band[{t (# - 1) + 1 , #}, {t #, #}, {1, 0}] -> et &,
     Range@i
     ],
    {i*t, i}
    ]
   ] /@ Transpose@IdentityMatrix[t]
```

Then

```
ArrayFlatten[ List /@ specialMatrix[2, 2]] // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

and

```
ArrayFlatten[ List /@ specialMatrix[2, 4]] // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

and so on.

Hope this  helps.

Comment: Edmund, thank you for your answer and +1. I was wondering if sparse matrix representation is the most efficient way to do computations with the big matrix. Also, can  the sparse matrix in mathematica be used to represent $I_{T}\otimes K$, where K has dim $T \times T$ and all entries non-null?

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the *obvious* (as far as I'm concerned) way to go about solving the problem at hand looks something like that:

```
With[{i4 = IdentityMatrix[4]},

  f[T_] := With[{iT = IdentityMatrix[T]},
    Flatten[KroneckerProduct[i4, #] & /@ iT, 1]
   ]

 ]
```

Taking into consideration the special structure of the desired matrix  $\left[\begin{array}{c} I_4\otimes e_1\\ \vdots \\ I_4 \otimes e_T \end{array}\right]$ we can define another function `customKroneckerProduct`:

```
With[{a = {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}, {4, 7}}, b = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}}},

  Clear[init];

  init[T_] := a + b (T - 2)

 ];

Block[{plastic},

  ClearAll[plus];
  SetAttributes[plus, Listable];

  plus[plastic[x__]] := List[x] + {4, 1};

  setup[T_] := NestList[
    plus[Apply[plastic, #, 1]] &, init[T], T - 1];

  customKroneckerProduct[T_] := SparseArray[Join @@ setup[T] -> 1, {T, T} 4]
 ]
```

It seems that `customKroneckerProduct` returns in approximately half the time-or even faster-it takes `f` to produce its results, *predominantly* for problem instances of large size:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the answer is not correct I think... I've added some more info on the question. Thank you for being willing to help me.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. you're really kind. I read mistakenly the subscripts in your question but I am confident the answer can be adapted; will try to as soon as possible; thanks!

Comment: +1 and thanks for the answer. ;)

Comment: you're welcome, thanks for the nice question

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

*(the function `construct2` has been updated to be simpler and a bit faster)*

The natural method to construct your matrix:

```
construct[i4_, it_] := Join @@ Table[
    KroneckerProduct[i4, Take[it, All, {k}]],
    {k, Length[it]}
]
```

Here's an alternative that does a single [`KroneckerProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerProduct), and then massages it's shape:

```
construct2[i4_,it_]:=With[{len=Length[i4],t=Length[it]},
    ArrayReshape[
        Transpose @ ArrayReshape[
            KroneckerProduct[i4, Transpose @ it],
            {len, len t^2}
        ],
        {len t^2,len}
    ]
]
```

Simple example:

```
r1 = construct[IdentityMatrix[4], Array[Subscript[a, ##]&, {2,2}]];
r2 = construct2[IdentityMatrix[4], Array[Subscript[a, ##]&, {2,2}]];

r1 === r2

r1 //MatrixForm //TeXForm
```

> True
>
> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{1,1} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  a_{2,1} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & a_{1,1} & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & a_{2,1} & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & a_{1,1} & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & a_{2,1} & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & a_{1,1} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & a_{2,1} \\
>  a_{1,2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  a_{2,2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & a_{1,2} & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & a_{2,2} & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & a_{1,2} & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & a_{2,2} & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & a_{1,2} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & a_{2,2} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Timing comparison:

```
m = RandomReal[1, {2000, 2000}];

r1 = construct[IdentityMatrix[4], m]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = construct2[IdentityMatrix[4], m]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {5.97644, Null}
>
> {0.725066, Null}
>
> True

**Addendum**

The OP asked about returning a [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) representation instead. Since most Mathematica functions work seamlessly with [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) objects, you just need to use [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) objects as arguments to `construct` or `construct2` to get out a [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) object. Consider the following two example $I_T$ matrices:

```
dense = RandomReal[1, {2000, 2000}];
sparse = SparseArray[Band[{1,1}]->RandomReal[1, 2000]];
```

Then for the dense matrix second argument:

```
d1 = construct[IdentityMatrix[4, SparseArray], dense]; //AbsoluteTiming
d2 = construct2[IdentityMatrix[4, SparseArray], dense]; //AbsoluteTiming
Head /@ {d1, d2}
d1 === d2
```

> {0.906973, Null}
>
> {1.42632, Null}
>
> {SparseArray, SparseArray}
>
> True

And for the sparse second matrix second argument:

```
d1 = construct[IdentityMatrix[4, SparseArray], sparse]; //AbsoluteTiming
d2 = construct2[IdentityMatrix[4, SparseArray], sparse]; //AbsoluteTiming
Head /@ {d1, d2}
d1 === d2
```

> {0.314939, Null}
>
> {0.087633, Null}
>
> {SparseArray, SparseArray}
>
> True

Summarizing, if both matrices are sparse, then use `construct2`, but if the second matrix is dense, use `construct`. In both cases the output will be a sparse array.

Comment: Carl, thank you for your answer. I like it. However, I'm not sure I should implement it, instead of sparse matrices, since I'll have to do some computations with the this big matrix. What do you recommend?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Please see update.

Comment: +1 thanks Carl ;)

Answer (score 0):

I must admit, I am not entirely sure what you are looking for, but might this be along the right lines?

```
I4 = {{i11, i12, i13, i14}, {i21, i22, i23, i24}, {i31, i32, i33, 
i34}, {i41, i42, i43, i44}}; MatrixForm@I4
```

[image: I4 matrix]

```
Transpose[KroneckerProduct[I4, #] & /@ Transpose[I4]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the answer is not correct I think... I've added some more info on the question. Thank you for the help.